# maya threejs export error has no attribute or method named 'ftn'

Tags: three.js, maya

I have maya 2016, on windows 10, with the maya exporting plugin from Three.js: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/maya

Installed it as per the instructions.

Tried exporting just a static model and am having these errors:

```
// Warning: file:     C:/Users/andrew/Documents/maya/2016/scripts/ThreeJsExportScript.mel line 12: The -bs/-borderStyle flag is obsolete and should not be used. //
// Warning: file: C:/Users/andrew/Documents/maya/2016/scripts/ThreeJsExportScript.mel line 29: The -bs/-borderStyle flag is obsolete and should not be used. //
// Warning: file: C:/Users/andrew/Documents/maya/2016/scripts/ThreeJsExportScript.mel line 39: The -bs/-borderStyle flag is obsolete and should not be used. //
// Warning: file: C:/Users/andrew/Documents/maya/2016/scripts/ThreeJsExportScript.mel line 54: The -bs/-borderStyle flag is obsolete and should not be used. //
file -force -options "vertices faces normals uvs materials diffuseMaps specularMaps bumpMaps copyTexturesMaps bones 4 skeletalAnim " -typ "Three.js" -pr -es "C:/Users/andrew/Desktop/proj/exported_name.js";
exporting materials
// Error: line 0: AttributeError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel\core\nodetypes.py line 408: nt.Checker(u'defaultPolygonTexture') has no attribute or method named 'ftn' //
// Error: line 0: Could not save file "C:/Users/andrew/Desktop/proj/exported_name.js". //
```

Anyone run into this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem and found your posting as I was searching for a solution.

So far, my short answer is that the maya plugin is crap. Here are some more specific things I've found that might be more helpful:

- It appears that the exporter ALWAYS exports ALL. So even if you choose Export Selected it tries to export all. That was causing it to export a bunch of stuff that wasn't ready for exporting and it would die. Copying the model I wanted to export into it's own scene allowed me to export without it crashing.
- When the plugin asks if you want to export the "diffuse maps" it actually means the Color map in a lambert shader. It does NOT export the Maya diffuse map.
- In general, the maya JSON output does not seem to be quite as well structured as the 3JS specification would like. It DOES load into the threejs.org/editor/ but if you then re-export from that the JSON is much better formed.

That's all I've got. I'm trying to see if I can improve the maya exporter, but I'm not an expert with Maya or Python.